# What is the rationale for using a triangular tail on a component?

Tags: interaction-design

[image]

I am writing guidelines for a flyout menu that appears when a user interacts with a button, icon, or some other element. All of the elements that would trigger this menu have an active / selected state. So I'm wondering why there would be a need to use this triangular tail. Can anyone here provide design rationale for applying a tail to the menu?

Answer (score 6):

I think it comes from comics, as a [speech bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon) (which turns out to be pretty ancient) analogy, as a kind of an affordance. Speech bubbles are commonly used in comics to indicate when a character is speaking or conveying a message. By using a similar design for tooltips or flyouts, designers can create a connection between the information being displayed and a specific element or feature within the interface.

When tooltips (or flyouts) are small enough, they rarely cause any confusion - they are small enough to keep close to their context.

[image: Tooltip example from Material Guidelines: without a caret tip]

But once they become bigger, without a caret tip (the "triangular tail"), users may be unsure which element the tooltip is associated with, or may confuse the tooltip with other elements on the page. The caret tip helps to clarify this relationship and ensures that users are able to easily access the information they need.

[image: Tooltip example from Carbon Design System: without a caret tip]

In addition, the use of a caret tip can make the tooltip feel more cohesive with the rest of the interface, as it mimics the arrow-like indicators used throughout many interfaces to indicate direction or action.

Notable examples of this are from [Carbon Design System](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/tooltip/usage/).

Comment: Bootstrap has it too, as does Foundation. I think the only framework that doesn't use arrows in tooltips is Material. In fact, the new version of Material (M3) doesn't even have tooltips!

Comment: The only issue is that within the design system I'm working on, the component is more like the overflow menu you see in the Carbon Design System. Their overflow menu does not have the triangular tail... So I'm trying to understand when a tail should be applied and when it shouldn't

Comment: @MadCM Overflow Menu is trying to mimic a dropdown, essentially. You open a menu to pick an action. It is interactive and contains buttons that are part of the form's UI, just hidden for whatever reason. Tooltip is more for information display, it doesn't contain actions, it's not interactive - that's why it looks so different and why they say it should not contain interactive elements. Now, there are components (like Popper, for example), that don't distinguish the two, but I'm sure it is beneficial for the User to see the difference.